# Windows 10 "low memory warning", "Commited" memory unaccounted for

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory

I have got a Window's 10 system that repeatedly runs into a Window's low memory warning, and occasionally applications getting killed/crashing (presumably due to not being able to get enough memory).

When I look in task manager, physical memory is within a wide margin, say 12GB/16GB, with 3GB of that being "System and compressed memory". However committed memory is near its 64GB limit (Window's 10 automatic page file management seems to have gone for 49GB).

However I can not account for that commited memory at all, the details tab shows the "System and compressed memory" as private working set, which I assume would expand/contract as needed, and adding up the "Commit size" column only got me to about 5GB.

So what is using up the other 50+GB and what can be done to stop it impacting the system?

[image: Task Manager Memory Tab]

Comment: Possible duplicate.   http://superuser.com/questions/500057/does-64bit-windows-8-low-memory-warning-have-same-limits-as-in-windows-7-x64?rq=1

Comment: install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), run WPRUI.exe, select "First Level, CPU, VAlloc, ResidentSet Analysis", run the trace for 30s-1 Minute. compress the generated ETL as zip/RAR/7z, upload the compressed file to Onedrive, create a share link and post it here. Maybe I can see the cause of your memory issues.